# Onion Architecture - What should an Interface do if has some Data to check after giving structured data (p.ex : an Object) to a Usecase

Tags: rest, onion-architecture

I have a REST API based on Onion Architecture.

But I have some challenges to apply this way of building a server. Concretely with what should be the behaviour of an Interface if has some data to check before giving structured data to a Usecase.

That is one of my problems:

I have some methods in the Interface that catch info about timers from the request. But I'm facing always the same question. Must I catch all and give to the Usecase and do all checks there, or instead of that, first I have to check if a timer exists in the DB (if i'm updating a timer) and after that do what I need?

This type of checks like Role of who is requesting and what is allowed to do or not, if timers exist, if user exists, if an user already exists and you can't create someone with the same username (I want an unique username restriction) etc, are annoying me because depending on where I'm doing the check, following strictly the Onion Architecture or not, I'm executing more or less code that sometimes is unnecessary.

If I check some things in the Interface, I am avoiding executing code that would be unnecesary. But I'm not following this Architecture correctly, and viceversa.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use a bus to solve this kind of checks. It requires to introduce couple of new concepts command, command handler and middleware. The bus takes command that are dispatched to the right handler (one per command). The power of  the bus is the ability to add new behaviour for each command: validation, unit of work. Maybe it does not exactly fixes all your problems, but that may be a lead worth to investigate

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have worked with a application state controller in VueJS ( that is a solution like a bus of events that also provides VueJS ) and if I understood your answer, is a similar concept that you are referring but in the backend, it's a great solution, I will check it, of course.